# how to get g++ package install in ubuntu 14.04LTS offline?

Tags: 14.04

since I am new to this society but I a using Ubuntu for last one and a half year.I was not facing any problems because it is best. My problem is that how to get g++ packages install in my computer in an offline way for 14.04 LTS version because I do not have any internet connections.Thank you to all the respected one's and thank you for making me as one of your family member.

Comment: Download the packages in anither PC with internet connection? Perhaps you should have been more explicit with your goal and requirements. You can [edit] the question anytime to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download g++ package for offline installation [here](http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-defaults/g++_4.8.2-1ubuntu6_amd64.deb). You can install the package with this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
```

For more packages, visit https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/g++.

Comment: Hello Vaibhav,Nice to see that Indian replied to it quickly. But I am getting confused which file or packages should be downloaded and how to work on it ahead.